# jQuery one not firing per element

Tags: jquery, html

I have some HTML code which creates three jQuery icons:

```
<span class="ui-icon ui-icon-circle-close one-click" data-customer-id="1"></span>
<span class="ui-icon ui-icon-circle-close one-click" data-customer-id="2"></span>
<span class="ui-icon ui-icon-circle-close one-click" data-customer-id="3"></span>
```

And some JavaScript jQuery code which I want to fire once per icon that is clicked. It works fine when I use this:

```
$(".one-click").one("click", function() { alert(this.dataset.customerId) } );
```

However, when I try to use one of my own functions it only fires for the first icon clicked. It never fires when another icon is clicked for the first time:

```
$(".one-click").one("click", function() { my_custom_function(this.dataset.customerId) } );
```

It works fine for the first icon that is clicked, but does not fire for the other icons that are clicked. The jQuery documentation says that it should fire once per element per event type. What am I missing? `my_custom_function` should execute for each element clicked...

Edit:

I should elaborate about `my_custom_function`. It actually reloads the spans from the web server. Specifically, they're enclosed in a div:

```
<div id="my_div">
    <span class="ui-icon ui-icon-circle-close one-click" data-customer-id="1"></span>
    <span class="ui-icon ui-icon-circle-close one-click" data-customer-id="2"></span>
    <span class="ui-icon ui-icon-circle-close one-click" data-customer-id="3"></span>
</div>
```

... and somewhere inside my_custom_function I reload using `$("#my_div").load("/some_url/")`. After commenting this load line out, the functions appear to be firing correctly. How can I apply the one-time-trigger functions after `load()`? Calling `one()` on the elements again doesn't seem to be doing the trick.

Comment: You're going to need to post the definition of `my_custom_function`.  Even better, create a [jsfiddle](http://www.jsfiddle.net) demonstrating the problem.

Comment: what is in `my_custom_function()`? are you sure it's not running? can you `console.log()` or `alert()` in that? are there any errors in console?

Comment: I thought `one()` only fired once per selector.  Can you try something like `$('.one-click').each(function() { $(this).one("click", function() { /* do stuff */ }); });` just to see if it works?

Comment: Seems to work fine from here: http://jsfiddle.net/Mfqm7/

Comment: It works fine when I test it: http://jsfiddle.net/JD8LF/

Comment: If that's all you're doing in your click callback, you might want to just pass `my_custom_function` as the callback instead: http://jsfiddle.net/mQfBr/

Answer (score 1):

take a look :

```
<span class="ui-icon ui-icon-circle-close one-click" data-customer-id="1">s1</span>
<span class="ui-icon ui-icon-circle-close one-click" data-customer-id="2">s2</span>
<span class="ui-icon ui-icon-circle-close one-click" data-customer-id="3">s3</span>
```

---

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    function my_custom_function(cust_id) {
        alert(cust_id);
    }
    $(".one-click").one("click", function() {
        my_custom_function(this.dataset.customerId);
    });
});
```

http://jsfiddle.net/F7Kdy/5/

Answer (score 0):

Either rewrite it as:

```
$(".one-click").one("click", my_custom_function),
```

or structure it as a callable function like this: http://jsfiddle.net/scott_in_ct/QbpC8/